Problems with run .net commands in Visual Studio Code in Ubuntu
I installed visual studio code in Ubuntu. Previously, i installed .net sdks in machine and i already put the commands in PATH. The commando dotnet --list-sdks works normally.
I created a symbolic link the dotnet folder in /usr/local/bin too:
sudo ln -s /home/user/dotnet /usr/local/bin/dotnet
I installed the "C# Dev Kit" extension in visual studio code, and when i try execute any command like ".NET : New Project", appears the error:
"The .NET Core SDK cannot be located: Error running dotnet --info: Error: Command failed: dotnet --info /bin/sh: 1: dotnet: Permission denied /bin/sh 1: dotnet: Permission denied. .NET Core debuggin will not be enabled. Make sure the .NET Core SDK is installed and is on the path"
What i'm doing wrong?
